# Any changes needed to Visual Basic PCL for Xamarin Unified API?

Tags: vb.net, xamarin, 32bit-64bit, portable-class-library

I have a Visual Basic PCL for Xamarin. Will I need to make any changes to the PCL to be able to use it in a Xamarin Unified API project? Or just recompile perhaps?

I read that Visual Basic code requires no changes for 64 bits unless you are using the fact that it's 64 bits, which I am not.

Comment: BTW Unified API is not released yet, so have not tried it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any changes to PCL projects. The only projects who needs updating is iOS and Mac. For more information on updating that see the documentation: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/updating_ios_apps/